# How do I add line numbers at front of ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor

I'm attempting to add line numbers just like Word in ckeditor, but I can't find the setting to do this.

Please see the screenshot below:

[image: Line Numbers in Word Example]

Comment: You can try https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/codemirror

Comment: I've tried, but codemirror only works in source code,right ?